# python table lookups: list of tuples vs. database

Tags: python, database

In python, I am working on a project that regularly involves computing how many objects with some given properties match certain conditions. I can see how to do this with lists of tuples or objects or a database, but I wonder if filtering a list of objects this way is the 'obvious pythonic' way to do it.

The options I thought of look like this:

```
list_of_all = [object_type(property0, property1, ...), ...]
number_of_matches = len(filter(object_type.property2_test(property2),
    filter(object_type.property1_getter, list_of_all)

list_of_all = [object_type(property0, property1, ...), ...]
number_of_matches = len([0 for candidate in list_of_all
    if candidate.property1 and candidate.property2 == property2])

list_of_all = [(property0, property1, ...), ...]
number_of_matches = len([0 for candidate in list_of_all
    if candidate[1] and candidate[2] == property2])

db_cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE table_of_all
    (property0 INTEGER, property1 INTEGER, ...)""")
number_of_matches = len(db_cursor.execute("""SELECT 1 FROM table_of_all
    WHERE property1 = 1 AND property2 = ?""", (property2,)).fetchall())
```

Using the last two in context of my code, timeit tells me that there is so significant difference.

```
$ python -m timeit -n 100 'import with_db' | tail -n1
100 loops, best of 3: 0.751 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -n 100 'import with_list' | tail -n1
100 loops, best of 3: 0.761 usec per loop
```

with both values somewhere between 0.751 and 0.811 every time.

In general, my use case consists of a few hundred (for testing purposes) up to at least 40000 objects. They are used in a simulation loop (no I/O to wait for). Every loop iteration consists of around 50 of these lookups, possibly finding the maximum of one property, and the update of two objects, but if there are other use cases where there is a best solution, that would also be interesting.

Is there a distinct better solution for this type of task, or is there a distinct type of task where chosing any of these solutions makes a difference?

Comment: Do whatever is easiest for you. If you use a database, you probably have more flexibility if your data are always going to be suitable for relational organisation.

Comment: How many objects are you going to have, do they change frequently or is the collection mostly static once built, and how often do you need to search? The algorithmic complexity for all of these data structures is well enough defined to make the choice easily once you know the use case—but if you've only got, say, 30 objects and you only search them every few seconds, performance is completely irrelevant and all that matters is which code looks more readable to you.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test it yet. Would using a pandas DataFrame be better than these in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can let the database do the counting:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_of_all
    WHERE property1 = 1 AND property2 = ?
```

In Python you can avoid creating an intermediate list by using `sum` and a generator expression:

```
sum(1 for candidate in list_of_all
    if candidate.property1 and candidate.property2 == property2)
```